# Wordpress plugin - T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a problem with a WP plugin:

http://gyazo.com/0c1a3577ee233a69d4c4cf5ae9783ad8.png

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING, expecting ')' on line 3

Comment: Please post the code instead of the picture!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to escape `'` in your third line.

```
array('"', '\\\'', "\n")
```

or

```
array('"', '\'', "\n")
```

if you want to replace `'` not `\'`.

Next time paste your code, not screenshot of it.